# How to resolve this problem with backup files in php

Tags: php, sql, select, backup

I have experienced about two times that mysql database crashes and it can not be connected for a long time and I always have to contact the hosting service to reactivate it...for some reason. So I want to create a mechanism to resolve this problem whit the backup file. heres the code:

```
<?php
$query = //some source
$db_user = "data_search";
$db_password = "password";
$database = "data_search";
$backupfile = '/data_search.sql';  
$db_table = "words";
$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

if ($db) {
    $result = mysql_query("
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            $db_table
        WHERE
            word = '$query'
        LIMIT
            0 , 1
    ");
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("
        LOAD DATA INFILE
            '$backupfile'
        FROM
            '$db_table'
        WHERE
            word = '$query'
        LIMIT
            0 , 1
    ");  
}

$num = mysql_numrows($result); 
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $word = mysql_result($result,$i,"word");
    echo $word;
    $i++;
}
```

Now this is only a sample and im 100% accurate that the error is in the backup `query($result)`. Basically what I want is to: if it cant connect to use the backup file. This returns `$num = 0;`  Can someone help me to execute this code? What `mysql_query()` am I looking for?

Comment: Use mysqldump for this instead.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysqldump` instead. You may start it from PHP:

```
/* get mysql database as gzipped backup file;
 * be aware, that the DB-password is stored in the ~/.bash_history,
 * if you include it in the program-call;
 */
shell_exec('mysqldump --host=DB_HOST --user=DB_USER --password=DB_PASSWORD --databases DB_NAME --skip-triggers --compact --no-create-info | gzip -9 > BACKUP_FILENAME-`date +%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss`.sql.gz')
```

Or just do that via a shell-script:

```
# !/bin/bash

REMOTE_DB_USER="my-database-user"
REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD="my-database-password"
REMOTE_DATABASE="my-database-name"
LOCAL_BACKUP_DIRECTORY="~/backup/dumps"
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ss`

# switch to local backup directory
echo "change dir";
cd $LOCAL_BACKUP_DIRECTORY

# dump whole remote database to gzipped file
echo "dump db to local"
/usr/bin/mysqldump --user=$REMOTE_DB_USER --password=$REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 $REMOTE_DATABASE | gzip -9 > dump-$CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

echo "finished"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MySQLDumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) (it is not the same as mysqldump!) You can program it to transfer DBs through FTP or per email so they don't get lost when the server crashes completely...

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest you use mysqldump, but I recommend you do this directly if you have shell access instead of having to deal with php timeouts and memory issues.

If for instance you are hoping to make regular backups then you should do this via a cron that runs a bash script.

**It would help if we knew the use case for this script.**